# Bash script to execute multiple Unix commands

Tags: bash, scripts

I have some commands that take too long to execute so I need a bash script to execute them serially.

The commands:

```
cd ~/my_file 
command 1 
command 2
...
command n
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a script using `nano my-script.sh`. Add [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and the commands or path to commands.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/command/1
/path/to/command/2
/path/to/command/3
```

Make it executable using [`chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chmod.1.html)

```
chmod +x my-script.sh
```

And run it using

```
./my-script.sh
```

Or as a one line command in bash:

```
command1 && command2 && command3 && commandN
```

This would execute the commands only if the previous command was executed successfully.

Comment: `command1 && command2 && command3 && commandN` would execute the commands *only if* the previous command was executed successfully. OTOH `command1; command2; command3; commandN` would executed all commands independently.

Comment: you can elaborate all the different ways on how to execute commands if you want : ) Feel free to edit the answer or write your own, i am too lazy : )